# Posting to facebook wall through browser

Tags: android, facebook

I need to post some text to user's facebook wall. Integrating facebook API is in consideration but before that I want to confirm that there is no easier way to do this.

Can we simply pass the data to be posted through post method to a facebook url? Let facebook detect that user is not authenticated and present the login screen in a browser, and after authentication is successful it continues with the wall posting task.

Is this possible yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)